# Rationalizing the denominator with radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd be thankful if someone could explain to me how to get the result with minus sign in front in this "rationalize the denominator" task: 
$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2-\sqrt[3]3}{\sqrt[3]4-\sqrt[3]6+\sqrt[3]9}$ [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E%281/3%29-3%5E%281/3%29%29/%284%5E%281/3%29-6%5E%281/3%29%2b9%5E%281/3%29%29).

I get the solution with the numerator numbers switched (therefore the minus sign)...

Ehm, as soon as I posted this question, I realized that I'm actually right, I solved it correct, I thought I didn't get the minus. I guess it's late, just delete this...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: if you want to delete you should select the delete link underneath the post. This will work unless you get upvotes / answers.